# Confuse with Generics and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, .net-4.0

I am new to c# and now bit confused with Generics and Entity Framework. I have two tables in database, which I retrieve in my code using Entity Framework. On my aspx page, I have a grid which should populate the data based on what table user selects.

In future there will be more tables. So I wanted to write a factory pattern to get the source list for datagrid. I can not make it to work because i am very confused.

Here is my code for BaseClass and two child classes.

```
static class Factory
{
    public static ReportBase GetReport(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Child1":
                return new Child1();
            case "Child2":
                return new Child1();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

//Base Class 
class ReportBase<T>
{
    public List<T> _list;
    public abstract void Load();
    public abstract List<T> Filter(DateTime statrtDate, DateTime endDate);
}

//Child 1
class Child1 : ReportBase
{
    public List<GetChild1> _list;
    public Child1(){}

    public override void Load()
    {
        //GetChild1 is the name of database table
        var info = from p in Context.GetChild1 select p;
        _list = info.ToList();
    }

    public List<GetChild1> Filter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var filteredValues = from p in _list where p.UploadedDate <= startDate select p;
        return filteredValues.ToList();
    }
}

//Child 2
class Child2 : ReportBase
{
    public List<GetChild2> _list;
    public Child2() { }

    public override void Load()
    {
        //GetChild2 is the name of database table
        return  (from p in Context.GetChild2 select p).ToList();
    }

    public List<GetChild2> Filter(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return  (from p in _list where p.UploadedDate <= startDate select p).ToList();
    }
}
```

Can Someone please correct the code accordingly? Do I have to use Generics here? I tried using it in BaseClass but it doesn't work properly, because I have to fix my child classes accordingly, for which I have no clue.

Comment: I have not looked at this in detail, but you have a typo in: "case "Child2": return new Child1();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, with generics you can write better code that is more readable and short.
I think it is better not to use a factory class for repositories in the end you need to know which type you are dealing with it in your code such as:

```
Child1 report = new Child1();
report.SomeBehaviorInChild1(); // this is not achievable with base class.
```

If you want to use this factory you can do the following:
    ReportBase report = Factory.GetReport();

Secondly, it is a bad idea to let your list public because you don't want to those who are using your class to create a new list from their code such as:
    report._list = new List();
You don't want this thing to happen to the objects in your class. So it is better to have your list private and depend only on the methods to return the data source of your report.
    private List _list;

```
public List<T> GetDataSource()
{
     return _list;
}
```

Thirdly, if you implement a generic reportbase you won't need to write the child classes unless they have something special that the base doesn't implement. 
Fourthly, the current implementation of Filter method is soooo bad because what you are doing here is getting all the records from database then filtering them in memory. This implementation is a bad practice. A better approach is to use the IQueryable which is a deffered execution object i.e. the result won't be populated until you request it.

```
public List<GetChild1> FilterExample()
{
    IQueryable<GetChild1> result = _context.GetChild1;
    result = from p in result
             where p.UploadDate < startDate;
             select p;
    //until this moment the query is still not send to the database.
    result = result.OrderBy(p => p.UploadDate);

    //when you call the ToList method the query will be executed on the database and the list of filtered and sorted items will be returned. Notice the sorting and filtering is done in the database which is faster than doing it in memory
    List<GetChild1> populatedResult = result.ToList();
    return populatedResult;
}
```

So this was a better approach to your problem. I think it is good for you to read a book called "More Effective C# 2008" it talks about queryable and linq in general.
Now if we apply this on your BaseReportClass we can get the following:

```
 //Base Class 
class ReportBase<T> where T: class
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public ReportBase(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    //I think GetAll is a more suitable name for your method than load :D
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Filter(Func<T,bool> filterFunction)
    {   
         var result = from p in GetAll()
                      where filterFunction(p)
                      select p;
         return result;
    }
}
```

Now to defining the additional behavior for the child classes.

```
//Child 1
class Child1 : ReportBase<GetChild1>
{
   public ReportBase(DbContext context):base(context)
   {

   }

   public List<GetChild1> FilterOnStartDate(DateTime startDate)
   {
        //I don't know if you are familiar with lambda expressions but if you are not you can research it on the internet.
        //The parameter here is converted into a method that its parameter is "p" of type GetChild1
        // and the body is "p.UploadDate < startDate".
        // Note you can remove the type of the parameter because the compiler can predict it.
        return Filter((GetChild1 p) => p.UploadDate < startDate).ToList();
   }
}
```

This is the code that uses your classes:

```
Child1 report = new Child1(new GetChild1Entities());
report.FilterOnStartDate(DateTime.Now);
```

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Hi Manar, Thanks ! One thing though, in my Load method, I have already saved the records in memory by converting it to list and saving them in private local list. In filter then I am querying the local list and not the database, so it isn't that bad or am I missing something? In my case, to improve performance, I am trying to load contents when Application_Start events fire and then I am holding the data in memory unless application pool is recycled at night. Is there a better way to do this. Does Entity Framework is roboust enough not to such work at start? Thanks again..really appereciated.

Comment: Hi. How are you? There is a thing wrong with getting all the data and put it in memory because as the data grow larger fetching the data and putting it in memory, more memory will be used in the application server, which affects the performance of your website. That is why it is better to filter data in the database and get only the needed data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Generics for defining how to display each entity type (or table) is the wrong approach.

Instead, using a pattern such as MVVM or MVC, where according to the type of the data (the model) you select a view.

[MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)
[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
[MVC for ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)

Comment: I am already implementing MVC that is why you dont see any view stuff in my classes which I posted above. ok, generics might not be the apporach here but how I get my child classes object in my factory? What should I write in my base class? It would be great if someone could correct these classes so that I could understand more. Thanks though.

Comment: Use a factory or better yet, reflection to choose the correct view class (e.g. the correct report class) for each model class. One approach is to use a dictionary of model class to view class (which you can serialize and deserialize from xml) to find the correct view class, then create an instance of it.